# unpack node_notifier within webpack and electron

Tags: angular, webpack, electron, node-notifier

I'm trying to get node_notifier working within an Electron app that is wrapped around webpack.

According to node_notifier's documentation, I need to unpack this module in order for it to work when packaged.

However, I'm not sure where this is done. Looking around the web, I've found little parts and pieces and thought that I needed to add this piece to the "build" property in the package.json file, but the app still fails to load.

```
"build": {
"appId": "com.app.id",    
"asarUnpack":[
  "./node_modules/node-notifier/vendor/**"
]}
```

After packaging for windows, and I browse to the resources/apps.asar.unpacked/node_modules folder (I'm assuming this is where it would show), I'm not seeing the module and subsequently, the app fails to run when installed on a windows machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, so not sure what changed.  Went back in and rebuilt and packaged and now it's showing up and the app is running on the windows machine and notifications are working....so...yeah....